# I'm having trouble connecting to the local server with the Flutter emulator

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an Instagram Clone application with Flutter. Accordingly, I wrote a simple API tool with Node.js for database (Postgre) management. Here is the code;

```
const express = require('express');
const { Client } = require('pg');

const server = express();
const client = new Client({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'instagram',
    password: 'postgre',
    port: 5432,
});

client.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Connected!");
});

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


server.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Request received:', req.body);
    try {
        const { username, password, email, fullname } = req.body;
        await client.query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('dssa', 'dssa', 'dssa', 'dssa')");
        res.status(200).send('User created successfully');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
    }
});


server.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await client.query("SELECT * FROM users");
        res.send(result.rows);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
    }
});


server.listen(5433, () => {
    console.log('http://localhost:5433 is listening... :)');
});
```

There is no problem with Node.js. I tested this and since it is connecting at the base. But I'm having problems on the Flutter side. Here are the codes;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  Future<void> getUser() async {
    try {
      final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://127.0.0.1:5433/users',
      );
      final response = await http.get(url);

      print(response);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('User created successfully');
      } else {
        print('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Exception occurred: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 25),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await getUser();
              },
              child: const Text('Get Users'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on the `Get Users` button, I get the following error;

```
Exception occurred: ClientException with SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 51908, uri=https://127.0.0.1:5433/users
```

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Emulator proxy settings;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your server, where you `server.listen(...)`, set your host to 0.0.0.0.

```js
server.listen(5433, 0.0.0.0, () => {
    console.log('http://localhost:5433 is listening... :)');
});
```

The reason for this is that localhost on your host machine is different than the localhost on your emulator or physical device, so, when your device or emulator is trying to hit `localhost`, it will not reach your server, so for your server to catch all bullets, setting it to `0.0.0.0` will open your server to the world lol

Comment: Can't it be done without opening it to the whole world?

Comment: well, it's not like anyone can easily access it, they'll have to know your public ip to access it from anywhere in the world, or if they are on the same network with you, they'll have to know your local machine's ip address to access your server or just use the loopback `127.0.0.1`. To answer your question, yes, you can set the host to your host machine's local ip address, then in your flutter app, you also use that local ip address as the host and the same port, so with this approach, only devices on your network can connect. `app.listen(5433, 192.168....)`